# Filtering with Formula Fields Is No Longer Supported

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

In SFMC Winter 23 release notes, there is an item which says "Filtering with Formula Fields Is No Longer Supported"

Specifically it states -
"Creating objects that use formula fields as a filter is no longer supported. Update your existing filters to avoid issues with formula fields. Support for existing filters is available until Spring ’23."

We currently have a formula field in CRM with a boolean value in Contact/Lead object which determines whether to sync that record to SFMC or not. Am I correct in understanding that with the change this filter won't work anymore? We contacted support but got contradicting answers.

Also, I would appreciate if you have any ideas on a possible simple solution in CRM to get around this if indeed this will stop working in future.

Thank you!

Comment: I just read this in the release notes. This sucks! Formula field is so much easier. Very annoying that they are changing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard solution is to just create a normal Checkbox field, and then populate it with an automation (e.g. Before Save Flows). You may need additional automations if you are using cross-object formulas; if a related record is driving the decision, you may need a Flow to make sure the checkbox is updated appropriately.